# Entity Framework. How to automatically update comboBox when data base table changes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am just starting with C# and Entity Framework (5.0) .
I have the following code that binds my combo box to my database table but when I update my list of employees the comboBox does not update automatically.
The only solution I can think of is to put the linq query into a separate method `update_cmbEmployees()` and call it every time I need it updated but this is not a very elegant solution  and can be messy in a complex application. So I imagine that there must be a better solution to a problems like this. Is there a some sort of event that I could hook up to? Or maybe I am binding it all wrong?

```
BindingSource bsCmbEmployees;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using( var ctx = new TimeKeepEntities())
        {
            var activeEEs = from ee in ctx.tblEmployees
                            where ee.Active
                            select ee;

            bsCmbEmployees = new BindingSource();
            bsCmbEmployees.DataSource = activeEEs.ToList();
            cmbEmployees.DataSource = bsCmbEmployees;
            cmbEmployees.DisplayMember = "Name";
            cmbEmployees.ValueMember = "EeID";
          }
   }
```

Edit1: Added entity framework version

Comment: Think again if you really need this. Seems like you are complicating things.

Comment: @Peter All I need is for the comboBox to display up to date list of employees. Do you have any suggestions how to do it without complicating things?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no way to "trigger" some event when data gets inserted/updated in EF. And I see no problem with your current approach.

Also I do not see how it can become messy in complex applications. I have worked on enterprise level multi-tier web/desktop applications with similar and more complex needs without having to write messy code. Would you please elaborate more on what problems you're facing in complex scenarios?